# Why was my Question Offtopic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions, on-hold-questions

I ask yesterday [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418150/paradox-or-error-in-design) Question and today it is marked as off-Topic.
After that I read the help Center Guidelines, but I miss the point why my question is not in the scope.

I hope someone can explain it for me.

greetings 
Chris

Comment: Probably some users felt the question would have been more appropriate on physics stack exchange instead of mathematics stack exchange.

Comment: Note: it's open, now (and has an accepted answer).

Answer (score 5):

**Note: The question has been reopened.**

---

Since there are so many questions to this site, often people do not have a lot of time to decide if a question is good. Your question may have looked bad to many users at first glance. Here are three possible specific explanations:

- They thought it was more fit for physicsSE.
- Due to typos, a web url link to an image, and capitalization issues, your post appeared to be of poor quality.
- The users thought your question was no more than a homework problem statement, without reading it through to carefully.

If this happens to you in the future, you can:

- Post your question to a chat room at [chatSE](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) to get it reopened, if the users in the chat room agree.
- Post your question to [Requests for Reopen Votes](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio) here on meta.

Comment: You forgot the last one, improve the question so it doesn't look like a bad quality homework question!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Good point, I agree with that also.